# How do I get Inspector Gizmo to leave Goal unattended?

Tags: deponia

I cannot figure out how to trick Gizmo to leave the room so I can wake Goal up. I suspect I need to start a fire somewhere, or steal from my ex girlfriend. I cannot figure out how to accomplish either.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about the part where Goal is in the Mayor's office?

Comment: When Goal is in the town hall, actually. The answer er below worked.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are in the room with Goal, there is a closet behind the stage on the right side with a cardboard box inside it. If you use your hand torch on the cardboard box, Gizmo will run over to put it out. When he does, close the closet door to trap him inside.